# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ESPnetASRModel:

Tags: pytorch, speech-to-text, speech

I am trying to run a hugging face espnet [pyf98/speechcommands_12commands_conformer](https://huggingface.co/pyf98/speechcommands_12commands_conformer). I loaded the correct versions for every library but facing this error of `Missing key(s) in state_dict:`

> RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ESPnetASRModel:
> Missing key(s) in state_dict: "encoder.encoders.0.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.0.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.0.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.0.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.1.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.1.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.1.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.1.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.2.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.2.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.2.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.2.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.3.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.3.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.3.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.3.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.4.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.4.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.4.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.4.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.5.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.5.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.5.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.5.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.6.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.6.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.6.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.6.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.7.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.7.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.7.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.7.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.8.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.8.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.8.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.8.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.9.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.9.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.9.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.9.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.10.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.10.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.10.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.10.conv_module.norm.running_var", "encoder.encoders.11.conv_module.norm.weight", "encoder.encoders.11.conv_module.norm.bias", "encoder.encoders.11.conv_module.norm.running_mean", "encoder.encoders.11.conv_module.norm.running_var".

How to get around this error?

Comment: Not enough information here to answer. Print the `state_dict keys` at a minimum.

Comment: how to find the `state_dict_keys`

Comment: `state_dict.keys()`

Comment: Without posting more information (for instance the place where you try to load a checkpoint) your question is unanswerable